# ASP.Net MVC Wrong Application Root Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've seen a few questions asked about this, but haven't seen any the same as it (or solved)... So here it goes...

I have two ASP.Net MVC applications, one nested inside the other...

```
example.com
---sites
------example1.com
```

Both sites technically work fine, however all URLs for the example1.com domain are resolved to example1.com/sites/example1.com/.

I have the application roots setup correctly in IIS and am using `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")` and `@Url.Content("~/images/image.png")` type references for links...

**UPDATE**

It looks like the host is showing the HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath is returning the wrong path, /sites/example1.com/ instead of just /.

Any ideas, things to try? Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it related to patterns?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Using a url rewrite seems super hackey... Got to be a way to get MVC to properly look at the application root... Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be that the host used some sort of a custom ISAPI extension to route domains to sub directories, and didn't create true application directories. So that explained all of the issues...